C# SMTP An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
My code acts very strangely because I get this error when I attach files and use await client.SendMailAsync(msg) and this only happens for some small images. Other images bigger or smaller than this works fine.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Here is my code.
public async Task<bool> SendEmail(EmailAccount emailAccount, string[] toemails, string subject, string message, IEnumerable<Attachment> attachments = null)
{
    bool succeed = false;
    try
    {
        using SmtpClient client = new();
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        
        client.Host = emailAccount.SMTPHost;
        client.Port = emailAccount.SMTPPort.Value;
        NetworkCredential credentials = new(emailAccount.UserName, emailAccount.UserPassword);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        using MailMessage msg = new();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(emailAccount.UserName);
        foreach (string toemail in toemails)
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toemail));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Body = message;
        if (attachments != null)
        {
            foreach(var attachment in attachments)
            {
                msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
        }

        await client.SendMailAsync(msg);    // Does not work
        //client.Send(msg);                 // Works
        Logger.LogInformation($"Email is sent successfully.");
        succeed = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogCritical(ex, ex.Message);
    }
    return succeed;
    //return Task.FromResult<bool>(succeed);
}

But using client.Send(msg) works with the attachment that fails with await client.SendMailAsync(msg)
Can someone explain why client.Send(msg) works but await client.SendMailAsync(msg) does not work for some attachments?
There are no asynchronous tasks before this code and the attachments are simply MemoryStream from Byte[] with CIDs.
